# DataSnapXE2 on Windows 7 Disconnected Gracefully

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap, c++builder-xe2

I Install datasnapxe2 tcp server on windows7 , after tow clients connect to server , one of these connections disconnected gracefully after some seconds , LifeCycle=Session ,
I testes it on some windows7 virtual it works fine , on another computer with windows7 same problem ,

Note that is same client and same server , same runtime libraries installed and tested

Is there need config win7 , TCP/IP for keepalive ? and how ?

Is there some win7 services running and make problems ?

Note the 3rd party applications running when tested :Teamviewer , Tightvnc , MS security essentials , skype , MS Messenger , ...

I remove these ( stoped them ) and the problem still

I belive there is something make one or more connections closed gracefully , with configuration of tcp/ip , But i search and found nothing ,

Would you reply ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading your RadStudio XE2 to Update 2 or higher because it's a bug on Update 1..I also had that problem then found out on their bugfixes on Update 2...

Try to run your server application on the Ide then run and connect to compiled executable datasnap client then try to execute server methods and wait for while then an Invalid pointer /Access Violation will show...that's the reason why clients prompt "disconnected gracefully"....

link: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41750...

Article:QC #:   Date Reported:  Area:
99616   10/4/2011   Database\DataSnap\Server
Description:    Steps:
[QC Short Description]
[FATAL] Datasnap Server exception XE2 SP1

[QC Description]
Datasnap Server / Client application build with XE2 SP1:
Server does throw EInvalidPointer / Access violation 
exceptions after more than 1 clients connected.
QC Entry 99616....